# How to read two strings from file and store them in two separate arrays

Tags: c, arrays, string, input, output

Looking forward to help...I need to read two strings from text files and store them into two separate arrays. I've searched, and got many codes, one of which worked, so I tried to modify it to read two strings. Here is my code:

```
int main(){
int i = 0;
int BUFSIZE = 1000;
char* words[20];
char* words2[20];
FILE *fp = fopen("input1.txt", "r");
FILE *fp2 = fopen("input2.txt", "r");
if (fp == 0){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error while opening");
    return 0;
}
words[i] = (char*)malloc(BUFSIZE);
words2[i] = (char*)malloc(BUFSIZE);
while (fgets(words[i], BUFSIZE, fp)) {
    i++;
    words[i] = (char*)malloc(BUFSIZE);
} 
while (fgets(words2[i], BUFSIZE, fp2)) {
    i++;
    words2[i] = (char*)malloc(BUFSIZE);
} 
printf("Output: \n");
srand(time(NULL));
int j = rand()%i;
int k = (j+1)%i;
fflush(stdout);
printf("%d - %s %d -%s", j, words[j], k, words[k]); 

int x;
for(x = 0; x<i; x++)
   free(words[x]);
   free(words2[x]);
scanf("%d", x);
fclose(fp);
fclose(fp2);
return 0;
}
```

But it won't work.Anyone knows why? Thank you!

Comment: Gee, I guess I'd store the stuff I want in one array in that array, and the stuff I want in the second array in that array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reset i = 0 before second loop and enbrace your free(x) code in curly braces

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int BUFSIZE = 1000;
    char* words[20];
    char* words2[20];
    FILE *fp = fopen("input1.txt", "r");
    FILE *fp2 = fopen("input2.txt", "r");
    if (fp == 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while opening");
        return 0;
    }
    words[i] = (char*)malloc(BUFSIZE);
    words2[i] = (char*)malloc(BUFSIZE);
    while (fgets(words[i], BUFSIZE, fp)) {
        i++;
        words[i] = (char*)malloc(BUFSIZE);
    } 

    // reset i back to zero
    i = 0; 
    while (fgets(words2[i], BUFSIZE, fp2)) {
        i++;
        words2[i] = (char*)malloc(BUFSIZE);
    } 

    printf("Output: \n");
    srand(time(NULL));
    int j = rand()%i;
    int k = (j+1)%i;
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("%d - %s %d -%s", j, words[j], k, words[k]); 

    int x;
    for(x = 0; x<i; x++){
       free(words[x]);
       free(words2[x]);
    }
    scanf("%d", x);
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you also know how to get the length of the two arrays? I tried len+=strlen(string1[i]); in the while loop, but it returned a value 1016.

Comment: The length of the two arrays should be the value of variable 'i' at the end of each while loop.

Answer (score 0):

More information is needed as to what is happening.  Do you get a compilation error, runtime message?  Did you check that the files exist?

Also, a few things should be fixed:

1. Your first line should include stdio.h
2. Add braces around the body of your for() to envelop both calls to free.
3. Does your compiler accept your declaration of x in the middle of the function like that?  If not, move it to the top.

Comment: 1. My code actually includes that, sorry for not posting it here. 2. Added now. 3. It accepts, so...I guess that is not the problem. In fact, my program just breaks when compiling, saying unhandled exception. The text file exist, anyway. The code works well when only one array is defined, but it goes wrong after I adds another array.